# SQL FETCH, Cursors and RPG

Tags: sql, cursor, rpgle, rpg, sql-fetch

I am not sure what is wrong with my code, I am trying to make a while loop that will fetch the next characters in the field (code) with a cursor  that is declared in SQL. The goal is to get the next matching characters with the loop. Then I want return the results at the end of the loop. The goal is to make a partial  match to the code, if there is no exact match. I have never used cursors before so I a trying to learn as much as I can about using fetch and cursors.

```
EXEC SQL
SELECT field FROM file
WHERE  field = :code

UNION

DECLARE UserInput CURSOR FOR
SELECT field FROM file
WHERE  field LIKE '%' || :code || '%'
ORDER BY field ASC

OPEN UserInput
FETCH NEXT FROM UserInput
BEGIN
   DO WHILE <> %EOF 
         FETCH NEXT FROM UserInput
END
CLOSE UserInput
DEALLOCATE UserInput;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow...lots wrong here...
At a quick glance...

1. you're trying to declare your cursor in the wrong place.
2. `%EOF()` works with RPG record level access, you need to be checking
   SQLCODE or SQLSTATE
3. `FETCH` `OPEN` are all SQL statements, need to be in an `EXEC SQL`
4. `DEALLOCATE` is not needed
5. Need to `FETCH` the row from the cursor into an RPG variable

Take a look at this code:

```
EXEC SQL                                            
  DECLARE UserInput CURSOR FOR                      
    SELECT field FROM file                          
    WHERE  field = :code                            
    UNION                                           
    SELECT field FROM file                          
    WHERE  field LIKE '%' || :code || '%'           
    ORDER BY field ASC;                             
EXEC SQL                                            
  OPEN UserInput;                                   
--really should check SQLSTATE here too!            

EXEC SQL                                            
  FETCH NEXT FROM UserInput INTO :MyRpgVar;         

Dow SQLSTATE = '00000';                              
   --note 00000 = no errors or warning              
   --     02000 = no data                           
   <do somthing?>                                   
   EXEC SQL                                         
      FETCH NEXT FROM UserInput INTO :MyRpgVar;     
ENDDO;                                              

EXEC SQL                                            
  CLOSE UserInput;
```

I suggest you read the [RPGLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzajp/rzajprpgi.htm) section of the **Embedded SQL Programming** reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will help me understand it much better!

Comment: one more thing, assuming `CODE` and `FIELD` are a fix length character fields, you probably need `'%' || trim(:code) || '%'`.

Comment: Though please do abandon the variant-characters, the _bar_ symbol "|", and replace the || as operator, with the CONCAT as operator.

Comment: Unlikely a result-set should include duplicates for any value meeting the equal predicate? Plus UNION is rather silly here. Just code an OR between the two predicates; depending on implied or actual N of optimize for N rows and actual number of rows in the table, perhaps code only the LIKE predicate [if, with trim].? Finally, depending on the _field_ data, the ordering requested may not effect exact-match-first, if there is an exact match and an inexact match; seems perhaps that exact-match-first may be desired from the descriptive [vs presentation of actual inputs and desired output].